# Very fast and scalable way to lookup of data for Java string pairs?

Tags: java, caching, lookup

I need to be able to look up information for pairs of strings (e.g. URLs) from a Java program. The information itself would be tiny, just a number, for example. However there would be millions and potentially billions of strings and I need to look up information for any two of them and I need to do this for a huge number of pairs, a huger number of times per second.

Ideally this would work as a cache: if a specific pair of strings is not stored yet, I would need to store the number associated with it. The total number of pairs to ever get stored in the cache will be much smaller than the total number of pairs possible.
Alternatively it could also be done by regularly adding new batches of pairs, maybe even re-creating the data structure. The first priority aim is to make the lookup fast without using up tons of memory.

This should be as fast as possible but because the number of pairs in the cache could be very large, I think it should not be an approach that depends on everything being loaded in memory.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I am pretty sure this must have been solved thousands of times before, but I would rather try and get this right from the start.

Comment: You are not specifying what you consider "fast". Is the trivial approach with a simple database too slow?

Comment: Fast would mean as fast as possible, given the constraints :)
The reason why I am asking is because there is a huge range of possibilities - and it is hard to know in advance how they would compare. For example even the "simple database" approach will probably show very different performance depending on which database is used, how configured etc. But then there are key/value stores, various trie implementations, and lots more.

Answer (score 3):

Most solutions assume either a) you have enough memory for the task or b) you are using a database.  If you want fast lookup access, I suggest making sure you have enough memory.  You can make the URLs more compact by encoding them as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 (which uses one byte per char)

Another option is to use a fast SSD and memory mapped files, but this is not trivial.

Even though the values are small, you still need to store the keys to ensure the lookup is correct.

BTW one billion strings using 100 bytes each requires 100 GB which is not as big as it used to be.  Certainly 100 GB of SSD doesn't cost so much.

Comment: I definitely wont have enough memory and this cannot be expected to use any specific hardware configuration either. So I guess what I am after is a solution where I can expect some kind of fast disk access combined with a good caching strategy to use the RAM that is available to get a good overall performance.
So if I go for using a database, would there be one that is specifically well suited for the task, and would there be a configuration that would optimize the DB for this kind of (ab)use?

Comment: @Johsm For me DB's are too slow, so I either don't need performance and I use them for reporting, or I use in memory.  If you want thousands of queries per second, then just about any data base should do the job.  If you want 100Ks per second, it will have to be in memory.

Comment: For me the best solution so far seems to be the Java interface to the Oracle Berkeley DB.